# java.lang.IllegalStateException at org.apache.catalina.connector.ResponseFacade.setBufferSize(ResponseFacade.java:285)

Tags: jsf, servlet-filters

I am using JAAS for authorization and authentication in an Java EE application. JAAS-like things have been omitted entirely for brevity in this question.

I am using a `Filter` that does authentication/authorization as follows (currently, there is only one line `response.sendRedirect()` to be focused/noticed).

```
@WebFilter(filterName = "SecurityCheck", urlPatterns = {"/WEB-INF/secure/*"})
public final class SecurityCheck implements Filter {

    public SecurityCheck() {}

    private void doBeforeProcessing(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException {
        //Do the JAAS authentication job here.
    }

    private void doAfterProcessing(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException {
        //Do the JAAS authorization job here and redirect accordingly based on a granted authority, if any.
        response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath()+"/admin/Home.xhtml");
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

        HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest=(HttpServletRequest)request;
        HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse=((HttpServletResponse)response);

        doBeforeProcessing(httpServletRequest, httpServletResponse);

        chain.doFilter(request, response);

        doAfterProcessing(httpServletRequest, httpServletResponse);
    }

    //The rest of the filter.
}
```

This filter is mapped to a given URL pattern `/WEB-INF/secure/*` where in the `secure` directory, there is only one page named `temp.jsp`.

This filter is invoked, when an `<h:commandButtn>` is pressed (which is meant for login) whose `action` is mapped to a managed bean as follows.

```
@ViewScoped
@Named
public class TestManagedBean implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public TestManagedBean() {}

    public void doLogin() throws IOException {
        ExternalContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
        context.dispatch("/WEB-INF/secure/temp.jsp");
    }
}
```

The XHTML code:

```
<h:form>
    <h:commandButton action="#{testManagedBean.doLogin}" value="Login"/>
</h:form>
```

The action method does a forward to the said JSP page that causes the above mentioned filter to be invoked.

The following line in the `doAfterProcessing()` method,

```
response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath()+"/admin/Home.xhtml");
```

causes the following exception to be thrown.

```
Severe:   Error Rendering View[/Test.xhtml]
java.lang.IllegalStateException
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.ResponseFacade.setBufferSize(ResponseFacade.java:285)
    at com.sun.faces.context.ExternalContextImpl.setResponseBufferSize(ExternalContextImpl.java:927)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.createResponseWriter(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:1163)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:403)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:134)
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:337)
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:337)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:120)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:219)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:645)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:415)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:282)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:175)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:561)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:565)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:545)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Info:   Exception when handling error trying to reset the response.
java.lang.IllegalStateException
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.ResponseFacade.setBufferSize(ResponseFacade.java:285)
    at com.sun.faces.context.ExternalContextImpl.setResponseBufferSize(ExternalContextImpl.java:927)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.createResponseWriter(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:1163)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:403)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:134)
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:337)
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:337)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:120)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:219)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:645)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:415)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:282)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:175)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:561)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:565)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:545)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Warning:   StandardWrapperValve[Faces Servlet]: Servlet.service() for servlet Faces Servlet threw exception
java.lang.IllegalStateException
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.ResponseFacade.setBufferSize(ResponseFacade.java:285)
    at com.sun.faces.context.ExternalContextImpl.setResponseBufferSize(ExternalContextImpl.java:927)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.createResponseWriter(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:1163)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:403)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:134)
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:337)
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:337)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:120)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:219)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:645)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:415)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:282)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:175)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:561)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:565)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:545)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

This exception occurs, when the context param `javax.faces.FACELETS_BUFFER_SIZE` is used in the configuration file web.xml as shown below.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.1"
         xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
                             http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
        <param-value>Production</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.FACELETS_BUFFER_SIZE</param-name>
        <param-value>65535</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>Test.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

The exception vanishes, when the said context parameter is removed or the redirect line along with the whole authentication/authorization job is moved to the managed bean from the said filter.

Does a filter not suffice for this kind of things, when the said context parameter is explicitly set in the web.xml file?

---

I am using,

- GlassFish Server 4.1
- Mojarra 2.3.0-m01 (the exception is not restricted to this version only)

I have tested this **exact** scenario by creating a plain simple blank playground project in which there are no additional resources/dependencies/web pages/managed beans/other utility Java classes than those shown here - no JAAS-like things have been used at all for the purpose of testing.

---

**EDIT:**

I got the same exception while testing the same scenario using Mojarra 2.2.9 on Apache Tomcat 8.0.9.0.

```
08-Feb-2015 20:57:22.890 SEVERE [http-nio-8084-exec-27] com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.handleRenderException Error Rendering View[/Test.xhtml]
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot change buffer size after data has been written
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.ResponseFacade.setBufferSize(ResponseFacade.java:265)
    at com.sun.faces.context.ExternalContextImpl.setResponseBufferSize(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.createResponseWriter(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(Unknown Source)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:503)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:136)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:526)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1078)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:655)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:222)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1566)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1523)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

08-Feb-2015 20:57:22.890 INFO [http-nio-8084-exec-27] com.sun.faces.context.ExceptionHandlerImpl.throwIt Exception when handling error trying to reset the response.
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot change buffer size after data has been written
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.ResponseFacade.setBufferSize(ResponseFacade.java:265)
    at com.sun.faces.context.ExternalContextImpl.setResponseBufferSize(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.createResponseWriter(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(Unknown Source)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:503)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:136)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:526)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1078)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:655)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:222)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1566)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1523)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

---

**EDIT 2:**

When the JSP page (temp.jsp) is replaced by an XHTML page, it throws the same exception but this time, it goes through relatively a different root.

```
Info:   Exception when handling error trying to reset the response.
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.faces.application.resource.ResourceHandlerImpl.createViewResource(ResourceHandlerImpl.java:120)
    at com.sun.faces.application.resource.ResourceHandlerImpl.createViewResource(ResourceHandlerImpl.java:72)
    at javax.faces.application.ResourceHandlerWrapper.createViewResource(ResourceHandlerWrapper.java:124)
    at javax.faces.application.ResourceHandlerWrapper.createViewResource(ResourceHandlerWrapper.java:124)
    at javax.faces.application.ResourceHandlerWrapper.createViewResource(ResourceHandlerWrapper.java:124)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultResourceResolver.resolveUrl(DefaultResourceResolver.java:77)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletFactory.resolveURL(DefaultFaceletFactory.java:269)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletFactory.resolveURL(DefaultFaceletFactory.java:362)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletFactory.getFacelet(DefaultFaceletFactory.java:240)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.buildView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:956)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:99)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:219)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:645)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:344)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:105)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at filter.LoginNocacheFilter.doFilter(LoginNocacheFilter.java:39)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:316)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:415)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:282)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:175)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:561)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:565)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:545)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

This time, I used,

```
@WebFilter(filterName = "SecurityCheck", 
           urlPatterns = {"/WEB-INF/secure/*"},
           dispatcherTypes = {DispatcherType.FORWARD})
```

before the given filter class.

Comment: Thank you for this post. I had the same issue with PrimeFaces and Atmosphere. I removed the javax.faces.FACELETS_BUFFER_SIZE context-param and I do not see this issue anymore. I am using JBoss EAP 6.4.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I reproduced your problem. There's definitely a lot of strange things happening here. First off, this filter never runs unless you explicitly set dispatcher type to `FORWARD`. I haven't tried GlassFish, but it doesn't run in Tomcat without that dispatcher type and for sure shouldn't do as per the servlet spec. Filters are by default dispatched on `REQUEST` only and resources in `/WEB-INF` are not publicly available.

As to the problem, the following happens once the command button is pressed, starting with JSF invoke application phase:

- JSF invokes bean action method.
- JSF bean action method invokes `ExternalContext#dispatch()` on a JSP file.
- Container locates `JspServlet` and prepares a new(!) JSP request/response.
- Container invokes that filter on JSP request (only if proper dispatcher type is set).
- Filter continues request via `FilterChain#doFilter()`.
- `JspServlet` writes JSP output to response.
- Filter invokes `sendRedirect()` on response and thus sets a `Location` header on an already written response(!). "Fortunately", JSP file was in my test case relatively small, so the response wasn't already committed at that point. This step would otherwise have failed with an `IllegalStateException: response already committed`.
- Filter returns.
- Container returns.
- JSF bean action method returns.
- Invoke application phase is finished, now render response phase begins(!).
- JSF starts to render response for the current view.
- JSF prepares response writer and checks if a buffer size is set, and if so, then set it on the response, which is actually the one as used by `JspServlet`, and is already being written to; this totally explains the particular exception.
- JSF renders current view to the response, which is actually the one as initially used by `FacesServlet`. This however gets totally lost as the container will actually continue with the JSP response.

There are two main problems:

1. You shouldn't do a `sendRedirect()` *after* `FilterChain#doFilter()`.
2. JSF shouldn't continue to render the response after `ExternalContext#dispatch()` on a "full" JSP page.

I'll leave solving the first problem up to you. As to the second problem, you need to instruct JSF via [`FacesContext#responseComplete()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/context/FacesContext.html#responseComplete()) that you've already completed the response by dispatching the current request/response to a "full" JSP page, so that JSF won't continue to render the response.

```
public void doLogin() throws IOException {
    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    context.getExternalContext().dispatch("/WEB-INF/secure/temp.jsp");
    context.responseComplete();
}
```

An alternative would be to use a real JSF page instead of a JSP page. The "nested" `JspServlet` invocation while the `FacesServlet` still runs is pretty .. scary.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is way more simple, when you use a requestfilter it implies that every single resource delivered by your server will pass through the filter including .css .js and every other resourse needed in order to reender your web page. so if your page need a .jsp  a .js and a .css your requestfilter will be call three times and your application will perform the sendredirect three times. I suggest you to do a simple validation something like:

```
if (httpServletRequest.getRequestURI().contains(".jsp")){
doAfterProcessing(httpServletRequest, httpServletResponse);
}
```

and move the chain.doFilter(request, response); to the function end.